# Failure of creating environment with "conda env create" for the same linux-64 OS

Tags: conda, virtual-environment

I have exported the virtual environment on my work machine which runs Ubuntu 16.04 to an "environment.yaml" file and then tried to use the file to create the same virtual environment on my home machine which also runs Ubuntu 16.04 but I got the following error:

Using Anaconda Cloud api site https://api.anaconda.org
Fetching package metadata .......
Solving package specifications: .
**Error: Packages missing in current linux-64 channels:** 
  - ca-certificates 2017.08.26 h1d4fec5_0
  - certifi 2017.7.27.1 py27h9ceb091_0
  - libedit 3.1 heed3624_0
  - libffi 3.2.1 hd88cf55_4
  - libgcc-ng 7.2.0 h7cc24e2_2
  - libstdcxx-ng 7.2.0 h7a57d05_2
  - ncurses 6.0 h9df7e31_2
  - openssl 1.0.2m h8cfc7e7_0
  - pip 9.0.1 py27ha730c48_4
  - python 2.7.14 ha6fc286_23
  - readline 7.0 ha6073c6_4
  - setuptools 36.5.0 py27h68b189e_0
  - sqlite 3.20.1 hb898158_2
  - tk 8.6.7 hc745277_3
  - wheel 0.29.0 py27h411dd7b_1
  - zlib 1.2.11 ha838bed_2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Conda version at my home machine was old which makes Conda look for old versions of packages. After I updating the Conda using the following command

`conda update conda`

The problem has been solved.

Comment: If it is solved you should consider marking the question as solved in order to help other users.